# How to filter a dataframe based on values in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have two dataframes, but I'm having trouble getting one to filter based on values in the other.

Example:

df1 has a bunch of columns, but column A is the one that matters because it corresponds to values in df2. Column A looks something like this:

| A |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| 1 |

df2 looks something like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.92 |
| 5 | 0.02 |
| 1 | 0.18 |
| 5 | 0.87 |
| 1 | 0.46 |

For the A value in each row in df1, I want to find the number of times B (in df2) is above 0.5 divided by the number of times the A value for that row appears in df2. So in df1, I'd like a new column called C, which would look like this in this example:

| C |
| --- |
| 0.33 |
| 0.5 |
| 0.33 |
| 0.5 |
| 0.33 |

My code to attempt this is as follows:

```
df1$C <- (df2 %>% filter(A == df1$A & B > 0.5) %>% summarize(n()))/(df2 %>% filter(A == df1$A) %>% summarize(n()))
```

If I try this but replace `df1$A` with some arbitrary number instead of the reference, it works fine. However, when I try to use the reference for each individual row in df1, I get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group them by `A` and then we can use double `inner_join`.

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(1,5,1,5,1))
df2 <- data.frame(A=c(1,5,1,5,1), B=c(0.92,0.02,0.18,0.87,0.46))
```

Solution:

```
df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>% 
               filter(A == df1$A & B > 0.5) %>%
               group_by(A)%>%
               summarize(count=n())) %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>% 
               filter(A == df1$A) %>%
               group_by(A)%>%
               summarize(A_count=n())) %>%
  mutate(C= count/A_count) %>%
  select(A,C)-> df1
```

Output:

```
 A         C
1 1 0.3333333
2 5 0.5000000
3 1 0.3333333
4 5 0.5000000
5 1 0.3333333
```

Comment: Just plugged that in and got the following error:

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `&...`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 3684 or 1, not size 37957.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In A == df1$A:
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: For what it's worth, that's the same error I got with the original code I tried

Comment: I tried again and have the desired output. Do one thing, just clear your environment and run the whole code from the data I have provided. You shouldn't have any more problems.

Comment: @fdafda12 did you try? Did you get the results?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, had some computer issues that prevented me from accessing the issue. That works but only when the lengths of df1 and df2 are equal; if we expand df2 to include any more data (which is the case in my actual data set), then I get the error message.

Comment: @fdafda12 are you getting an error message or a warning message? Can you update the question with the desired output?

Comment: It's a warning message, and I've just realized that it works despite the warning message. It says: 
1: In A == df1$A :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In A == df1$A :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

It's the same desired output as the question, but df2 expands to:
df2 <- data.frame(A=c(1,5,1,5,1, 15, 25), B=c(0.92,0.02,0.18,0.87,0.46, 0.92, 0.05))

Does the warning message even matter?

Comment: @fdafda12 It will disappear if the length of one data frame is multiple of another. But in any case, you will get the desired output. If that solved your purpose then please consider upvoting and selecting it as the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. It will help others in future.

Comment: Done, thank you!